# How can I tell what triggered endRequest function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Working on an asp.net website. All the controls are in an UpdatePanel.

I have some js code on my page. For some reason after docment.ready is called add_endRequest is being called (repeatedly). I've been trying to troubleshoot why this is being called, but I can't figure it out. What is the best way to tell what triggered endRequest? Any suggestions as to troubleshooting? Here's some of the code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // code....
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        alert('add_endRequest')
        // code
        alert('add_endRequest done');
    });
```

Comment: kinda suprised this still survives since so broad, please mark an accepted answer or self-answer and accept so marked as solved. If still curious, i would recommend http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or 'maybe' http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, search there heavily first though, or even just look for tutorials on debugging since its been answered so many times before, just usually very abstract (design principles) or for a specific context (which you can usually relate to your own without much effort effort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way (since its just the javascript side) is to use the Sources panel.

Ive used this on Chrome mostly, but I know comparable exists in other major browsers too.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

> The **Sources** panel lets you debug your JavaScript code. It provides a graphical interface to the [V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/) debugger.

Find the line you want to put a breakpoint on, click the line number then see the stacktrace and other info in the right.

You can use that to start looking at what is triggering and place other breakpoints if required to see the local variables that helped cause this.

You can also use this to make local changes to a file, though ofcourse when you refresh these are lost, but it can be useful for quick debuging too.

---

As a sidenote, if you are wanting broad advice like this probably best you take a look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, some awesome resources there too.

Comment: Thanks @DanielBrose I'll check it out! :)